# Finding the bad formula in Excel "unreadable content"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting the error:

"Excel found unreadable content in '[filename].xls'. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes."

The error is being caused by a bad formula. I know, because if I turn off the VBA lines that add the formulas to the sheet, it works fine. Right now I'm commenting out rows (of a couple hundred) to figure out where the problem is.

Is there an easier way? The error dialog doesn't say where the problem is, nor does the log file. Is there anywhere where the problem can be diagnosed?

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29029488/excel-vba-for-on-error-goto-next

Comment: Also, there is functionality in Excel to trace errors. Formulas tab > Formula auditing.