# Unreliable behavior - Excel VBA Code - Precedents.Count Statement

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I have this apparently a very simple Excel VBA Sub.

```
Public Sub CheckRef()

Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In Selection
    On Error GoTo MyNext
    If IsNumeric(Cell.Precedents.Count) Then
        MsgBox (Cell.Address)
    End If

MyNext:
Next Cell

End Sub
```

If a cell in selection has Precedents, Message Box Cell address. If it errors out just proceed to Next Cell in For loop.

This code gives

> run time error 1004 'No Cells were found'

despite On Error statement. Ironically for the first instance it correctly skips, but errors out on next as seen in this Screenshot to GIF.

`Selection C2:C4 C2 =SUM(A1+A2)` (Msgbox),  `C3 =7+9` (Escapes correctly) `C4 =7+9`

> (Run time error 1004)

I am puzzled on what mistake am I making here. Just to mention it's Excel 2013 SP1 and in VBA Tools-->Options-->General-->Error Trapping-->Break on unhandled errors is selected by default. Any further help would be great.  Thanks.

#### Screenshot to GIF

[image: Screenshot to GIF]

Comment: You need to `Resume`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653287/vba-error-handling-in-loop & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11998836/excel-vba-on-error-goto-statement-not-working-inside-for-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your error handling

```
Public Sub CheckRef()

Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In Selection
    On Error GoTo MyNext
    If IsNumeric(Cell.Precedents.Count) Then
        MsgBox (Cell.Address)
    End If
MyNext:
Resume MyNext2:
MyNext2:
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Your error handling has already been used on the first loop, so the above is fix to 'reset' it using `resume`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
Public Sub CheckRef()

    Dim Cell As Range, qwerty As Range

    For Each Cell In Selection
        Set qwerty = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
            Set qwerty = Cell.Precedents
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not qwerty Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox (Cell.Address)
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```