# Catching Timeout on VBA WinHttpRequest

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, error-handling, timeout

I want to set Timeout values and catch this event if it happens using VBA and Excel. So far I tried with XMLHTTP60 and WinHttpRequest:

```
    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    With XMLHTTP
        .setTimeouts 11, 11, 11, 11 'Values for testing to get a timeout
        '.setTimeouts TIMEOUT_LRESOLVE, TIMEOUT_LCONNECT, TIMEOUT_LSEND, TIMEOUT_LRECEIVE
        .Open "GET", currenturl, False
        .send
        '.waitForResponse 1 'testing
        If .responseText Like "*PATH_NOT_FOUND*" Or .responseText Like "*OUTSIDE_BOUNDS*" Then
            noroutefound = True
            GoTo skiploop
        End If
        str = Split(.responseText, "{""startTime"":")
        complstr = .responseText
    End With
```

However, I am unable to catch an Error caused by a Timeout, or a Timeout itself.

How can I catch a Timeout?

Comment: add error handling of on error go to errhand and in the errhand print the err.message

Comment: @QHarr True that. I now figured out my Error was inside my Errorhandler... Feel free to post this as answer

Comment: Added code formatted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add error handling of `On Error GoTo errHand` before expected error and in the errHand: make sure you have

```
'Code
On Error GoTo errHand:
'Code producing error
Exit Sub
errHand

If err.Number <> 0 Then
     Debug.Print err.Message
End If
Exit Sub
```

If you have the error number of interest you can use select case err.Number to handle your specific error in a tailored way like for example:

```
errHand:

Select Case Err.Number
    Case -2147012894 'Code for Timeout
        Msgbox "Timeout"
    Case -2147012891 'Code for Invalid URL
        Msgbox "Invalid URL"
    Case Else 'Add more Errorcodes here if wanted
        MsgBox "Errornumber: " & Err.Number & vbnewline & "Errordescription: " & Error(Err.Number)
End select
```

Comment: Turned out the Error is only catched once. In the next loop it just ignores ErrorHandler at all. But only this particular Error. Cant be normal right?

Comment: You would want resume next in the err handler to continue execution as well as err.clear

Comment: Resume does the trick. Explanation [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10356467/8947209)